# How do I install KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde

I want to have both KDE and Gnome shells on Ubuntu. Ubuntu only has Gnome installed by default. How do I install KDE?

Comment: If you plan on using KDE heavily in 2024, I strongly recommend `kde-standard`. This is because `kde-plasma-desktop` is missing a bunch of stuff like icons and widgets (eg quicklaunch)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to install the `kubuntu-desktop` package for the full install with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Then the next time you login you can choose what to use from the login screen (under Session).

Comment: what about the sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop... i tried it .. but seems to give minimal GUI features.. how do i add to it?

Answer (score 10):

To get just the plasma environment (on 12.04 and newer):

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop
```

It worked fine for me on 15.10

Comment: +1 and this is valid for 12.04 and newer releases.  Also, there is `kde-plasma-desktop` for users who want desktop environment with minimal set of applications.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to log in from KDE run `sudo apt-get install kdm`, `sudu apt-get remove gdm`, and `dpkg reconfigure kdm`.

Answer (score 8):

Just try the following command in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Then just select KDE on the login manager.

Answer (score 4):

On **30/09/2015**:

To install KDE on **Ubuntu  (12.04,14.04,14.10,15.04,15.10)** (plasma 5.3)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

To install KDE on Ubuntu (**15.04,15.10**) (plasma 5.4)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ci/stable
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Note: To install plasma 5.4,you need to remove backports ppa.

[launchpad.net/backports](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+index?field.series_filter=trusty&batch=75&memo=225&start=225)

[launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/stable](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)

Comment: did you get plasma 5.4 (not 5.3) from ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: I think I didn't mentioned in my answer =)

Comment: thanks for the super fast response! Pls have a look at this post which i just posted regarding a issue getting plasma 5.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/691331/ended-up-having-kde-4-x-plasma-4-instead-of-plasma-5-4-from-ubuntun-14-04

Comment: I will @KillBill :)

Comment: @KillBill please run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` and let me know the result =)

Comment: thanks mate! it says: 27 to upgrade, 203 to newly install, 0 to remove and 556 not to upgrade.
Need to get 92.5 MB/161 MB of archives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30849/discussion-between-ravan-and-killbill).

Answer (score 3):

Just open synaptic (If not installed yet, install it by ubuntu software center) and search for **desktop environment** and install plasma-desktop

Answer (score 2):

I think the most complete answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135267/whats-the-difference-between-kde-packages). According to what you want to install (only the GUI or GUI+some packages).

Citing the content of the answer:

> `plasma-netbook` and `plasma-desktop` differ only by whether they
>   install the netbook or the desktop interface. `kde-workspace` is
>   identical to `plasma-desktop`.
>
> `kde-plasma-desktop` will install a few KDE programs: Dolphin,
>   Konqueror, kde-baseapps, konsole, kwrite, and kde-passwd.
>
> `kde-standard` installs a bunch of stuff on top of `kde-desktop`:
>   Akregator, Ark, Dragonplayer, gnupg, Kaddressbook, Kate, KDE
>   wallpapers, Kmail, etc.
>
> `kubuntu-desktop` installs even more than `kde-standard`. `kubuntu-desktop`
>   is the package you would download from the Ubuntu website if you
>   wanted Kubuntu, but if you only want the Plasma interface, not any of
>   the default programs, `plasma-desktop` might be sufficient.

Choose the package you want and then run `sudo apt-get install package-name`