# How do I install KDE on my 11.04

Tags: unity, installation, gnome, package-management, kde

I want to get rid of the Unity thingy (who came up with this?).
KDE seems the best choice.
All the instructions, including this [How do I install KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417/how-do-i-install-kde-shell-on-ubuntu) mention the Ubuntu software center.

1. I have no idea how to get to it in the new UI, how do I get to it?
2. I assume the apt-get install is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have installed Ubuntu 11.04 but you haven’t liked the Unity. You want to try another window manager like KDE. So you can install Kubuntu, it comes with KDE.

To install Kubuntu, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

During the installation, you will be asking about which display manager you want to leave as default. Choose kdm.

Now, if you want a full KDE installation that include multimedia, networking, graphics, education, games, system administration tools, and other artwork and utilities, still in the terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

After that, restart your computer and in login screen, don`t forget to select KDE