# How To Install KDE Plasma Desktop On Ubuntu?

Tags: kde, plasma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install KDE shell on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417/how-do-i-install-kde-shell-on-ubuntu)

Hey guys I am new to Ubuntu, I have installed Ubuntu 11.10, with Gnome, and i am not so happy with unity, I want to install KDE plasma, can I install KDE plasma on Ubuntu, or I have to download entire OS again to have KDS Plasma Desktop.