# What's the difference between KDE packages?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, kde

So I'm going to install KDE in Precise. I found that there wasn't an entry for Plasma Desktop (only KDE apps) in the software center, so I fired up Synaptic to look for the packages.

However, now I'm finding way too many of these. There's `kde-standard`, `kde-workspace`, `plasma-desktop`, `plasma-netbook`, `kde-plasma-desktop`...

I went and looked online, but with differing instructions, too. I think the most common were between "install `kubuntu-desktop`" and "add the `kubuntu-ppa/backports` repo" (which is probably not the one I want).

My question is... what's with all these different packages? Is there any difference between them? Which one should I install?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've checked the packages that `apt-get install` would install for each of these. These aren't complete lists, but only list the differences from my Unity (ie., without any KDE programs) setup.

`plasma-netbook` and `plasma-desktop` differ only by whether they install the netbook or the desktop interface. `kde-workspace` is identical to `plasma-desktop`.

`kde-plasma-desktop` will install a few KDE programs: Dolphin, Konqueror, `kde-baseapps`, `konsole`, `kwrite`, and `kde-passwd`.

`kde-standard` installs a bunch of stuff on top of `kde-desktop`: Akregator, Ark, Dragonplayer, gnupg, Kaddressbook, Kate, KDE wallpapers, Kmail, etc.

`kubuntu-desktop` installs even more than `kde-standard`. `kubuntu-desktop` is the package you would download from the Ubuntu website if you wanted Kubuntu, but if you only want the Plasma interface, not any of the default programs, `plasma-desktop` might be sufficient.

Comment: Excellent. I just might install `kde-plasma-desktop` considering that some of the GNOME programs don't exactly look "in place" in KDE.

Comment: Great explanation, but I'm a bit unsure as to where kde-desktop fits in the hierarchy. Also, which additional packages specifically does kubuntu-desktop install (or could you give some examples)?

Comment: This thread is 18 months old and three releases out of date. Run `apt-cache depends` to see what packages would be installed by any of the metapackages above.

Comment: There isn't any mentioning of `kde-full`. What does that package offer in addition. Or is it actually the equivalent of `kubuntu-desktop` currently?

Comment: The easiest way to check what would be installed is to run `apt-cache depends` or `apt-get install` (and decline the installation). kde-full is a superset of kde-standard, and kubuntu-full is a superset of kubuntu-desktop, but kubuntu-desktop really is separate from kde-standard - I think kubuntu-desktop includes a bunch of ubuntu-specific packages, and excludes various others.