# Am new to Kubuntu. First time tried it on Flash-drive. Desktop had only one icon on it. Entitled "Install". Any help please?

Tags: usb, kubuntu, kde, testdrive

KDE scared me, mostly because I'm new and unfamiliar with it. I set it up on a flash-drive to try it out and all the desktop had was one icon that said "Install". My hard drive runs both Ubuntu and Winslows. I would like to try KDE before doing any permanent install. How do I do this?

Comment: You booted the flash drive with KDE in "Try KDE" mode, and once it boots, you're running KDE. Try it out from there. It'll be a little slower than if you ran from a HDD/SDD, but it's the full KDE environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417/how-do-i-install-kde) – no need to install a complete new operating syste.

Comment: @DavidFoerster From very recent personal experience, I wouldn't recommend adding KDE to a system already running Unity to a newcomer which is what I assume the questioner to be. I mostly agree with https://askubuntu.com/a/680006/248158 even though the answer maybe a little scary.

Answer (score 1):

[image: IMG:]
The Kickoff default application launcher icon in Kubuntu 17.04 looks like this. Kickoff is the default application launcher in Kubuntu that provides a click-through interface for finding and launching applications. The Kickoff icon is located in the bottom panel at the bottom left corner of the Kubuntu desktop. Kickoff has a search facility, allowing you to type the name of the application or its description to find it.

[image: IMG:]  The Kickoff default application launcher icon in Kubuntu 16.04 looks like this.