# how to revert from KDE installation?

Tags: unity, gnome, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417/how-do-i-install-kde) to install KDE with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` but would like to revert my changes. Is it possible?

I tried running `sudo apt-get autoremove kubuntu-desktop` as suggested by user535733 and got this output

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ark baloo-kf5 cdrdao cryfs cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs
  cryptsetup-run dolphin elisa encfs ffmpegthumbs geoip-database go-mtpfs
  gstreamer-qapt gwenview haveged kaccounts-integration kamera kate kate5-data
  kcalc kde-config-tablet kde-config-whoopsie kde-spectacle
  kdegames-card-data-kf5 kdegames-mahjongg-data-kf5 kdegraphics-thumbnailers
  kdenetwork-filesharing kimageformat-plugins kio-audiocd kmahjongg kmines
  konversation konversation-data kpat krdc kross ksudoku ksystemlog ktorrent
  ktorrent-data kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-wallpapers
  kubuntu-wallpapers-focal kubuntu-web-shortcuts lame libcfitsio8
  libdolphinvcs5 libfreecell-solver0 libgeoip1 libhavege1
  libkf5baloowidgets-bin libkf5baloowidgets-data libkf5baloowidgets5
  libkf5cddb-data libkf5cddb5 libkf5compactdisc-data libkf5compactdisc5
  libkf5kdcraw5 libkf5kdegames-data libkf5kdegames7 libkf5kdegamesprivate1
  libkf5kipi-data libkf5kipi32.0.0 libkf5kmahjongglib-data libkf5kmahjongglib5
  libkf5krosscore5 libkf5krossui5 libkf5modemmanagerqt6 libkf5plotting5
  libkf5sane-data libkf5sane5 libkf5syndication5abi1 libkf5torrent6
  libkf5unitconversion-data libkf5unitconversion5 libkf5webkit5 libkpmcore9
  libktorrent-l10n libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libopenconnect5 libperl4-corelibs-perl libqt5webengine5 libqt5webkit5
  libqt5xmlpatterns5 libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-plasma libreoffice-qt5
  libsignon-extension1 libstoken1 libtinyxml2-6a libtomcrypt1 libtommath1 muon
  partitionmanager pastebinit pavucontrol-qt pavucontrol-qt-l10n
  plasma-calendar-addons plasma-dataengines-addons
  plasma-discover-snap-backend plasma-nm plasma-runners-addons plasma-vault
  plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons plasma-workspace-wallpapers
  print-manager python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5 qapt-deb-installer
  qml-module-org-kde-kaccounts qml-module-org-kde-prison
  qml-module-qt-labs-platform qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
  qml-module-qtwebengine qml-module-qtwebkit sddm sddm-theme-breeze
  signon-kwallet-extension signon-plugin-password signon-ui-service
  signon-ui-x11 signond skanlite ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt usb-creator-kde
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 130 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
After this operation, 359 MB disk space will be freed.
```

Comment: It's possible to *uninstall* all the kubuntu-related packages, returning your system to quite close to before you started. It's not possible to *revert* (undo) all changes that you have potentially made. Apt does not have an "undo" feature. For example, your boot splash screen will remain Kubuntu untill it is superseded by something else.

Comment: So what's wrong with the proposed removal? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: It might help to say what you want to revert to - I'm guessing you mean 'can I change my desktop back to Gnome' or similar? If you didn't uninstall your previous desktop then you may be able to select it on the login screen.